# Can we add a non-primitive field to an existing class using javassist?

Tags: java, javassist

I'm a newbie to Javassist, and I've already read some tutorials related to it.

Because I need do some bytecode injection in each method enter or before the method exit, and get some statistics from this.

Through the online javassit tutorial, I find that we can make a new field to an existing class:

```
CtClass point = ClassPool.getDefault().get("Point");
CtField f = new CtField(CtClass.intType, "z", point);
point.addField(f);
```

But the type of the CtField only contains primitive type by default, can we add a new field whose type is non-primitive, for instance, ArrayList?

If I can add the new ArrayList field to the existing class, since the class doesn't import java.util.ArrayList, will it cause compile error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can add non-primitive fields. You just need to get a handle to the class for the field, normally via ClassPool. Note that you will need the fully qualified name of the class you want to use:

```
CtClass arrListClazz = ClassPool.getDefault().get("java.util.ArrayList");
CtClass point = ClassPool.getDefault().get("Point");
CtField f = new CtField(arrListClazz, "someList", point);
point.addField(f);
```

Comment: Thanks, the above code means that we add the new ArrayList member someList to the point class, but in the point class we didn't import the java.util.ArrayList, will this cause the compile error?

Comment: Well, your adding the ***bytecode*** that represents a java.util.ArrayList field, not an actual English language string. Import statements are just compiler directives that do not appear in the compiled class file. Which is, by the way, why you need to use a fully qualified name (FQN) when searching for classes in the ClassPool.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see. I think I should spend some time studying the  bytecode. One more question, hopefully you can help me, is it possible  for the someList memeber to be a generic type, like ArrayList<someClass> someList?

Comment: Generics don't exist at the byte code level. They are 'syntactic sugar' for the compiler, aka they disappear once the source code is compiled.

Comment: Thats odd, this exact line of code works perfectly for me - `CtClass stringClazz = ClassPool.getDefault().get("java.util.ArrayList");`

Comment: @LifeOnCodes - glad it works. Please do feel free to accept my answer if it helped you. I'd be glad to answer your other question but please post it as a separate one on, so it can benefit others as well.

Comment: @Perception I am trying the code snippet shared by you but how do I read the value for that newly added field? I tried the reflection code but it is not working. Do you have any thoughts on how to read the value of the dynamically addeded field?

Comment: @Metalhead :I guess by now you found the solution for that. I am in need of a situation where i need to add the instance through javaassist and initialize it through reflection but when i read the class fields through reflection . I cant read it .. can you please explain me how to do it ?

Comment: Does this have to be in a ClassFileTransformer?